# How to update cocoapods in Swift 4.2 xcode 10

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I can't update my razorpay cocoapods in Swift 4.2 and xcode 10. I using podfile name is pod 'razorpay-pod', '1.0.24' But I used both pod install and pod update command to update my cocoapods. it's getting error like this

here is my error in terminal

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "razorpay-pod":
In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
razorpay-pod (= 1.0.22)

In Podfile:
razorpay-pod (= 1.0.24)

razorpay-pod

Specs satisfying the `razorpay-pod, razorpay-pod (= 1.0.24), razorpay-pod (= 1.0.22)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: the minimum ios version supported by razorpay-pod is iOS 10, check if your project's targeted iOS version is less than 10

Answer (score 1):

As the debug output says:

```
Specs satisfying the `razorpay-pod, razorpay-pod (= 1.0.24), razorpay-pod (= 1.0.22)` dependency were found, but they **required a higher minimum deployment target.**
```

Look up what that minimum deployment target for `razorpay-pod` is and set your project's deployment target to that.

Comment: how  can we check what is minimum target?

Comment: By looking at the libraries' resources. See https://razorpay.com/docs/ios/, it's shown at the top.

Answer (score 1):

To update `CocoaPods` you simply install the gem again

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

Or for a pre-release version

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Then try pod update on you directory.